# Match the last 3 letters of words in a string using regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string "cough\tbough" or "quod erat demonstrandum\
tand that, ladies and gentlemen, is the end of my memorandum". And i need to check if last 3 letters of last words of this sentences are equal. But backslash is confusing me.

```
pairOfLines="cough\tbough"
pattern = ?????
match = re.match(pattern, pairOfLines)
return match.group(1) == match.group(2)
```

Comment: Not quite clear about the question? Why you need regrex?

Comment: Do you actually have a string with a backslash, or does the string contain a tab character?

Comment: it's a task, which i need to solve.I need to solve it by using regexp match

Comment: This feels like a homework question. If it is, you should be clear about that.

Comment: Hint: the backslash in the target string looks like part of "\t", which is usually a printf-style way of encoding a tab on an output string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re

pairOfLines="cough\tbough"

m = re.match(r'.*?(\w{3})\b.*?(\w{3})\b', pairOfLines)
print(m.groups())
('ugh', 'ugh')
```

- `.*?` - match anything before the first group
- `(\w{3})\b` - 1st capture group, of which

  - `\w{3}` - 3 letters
  - `\b` - word boundary - indicating that the letters must lie at the end
- `.*?` - match anything before the second group
- `(\w{3})\b` - 2nd capture group, similar to the first

---

You could also use `re.findall` to the same effect:

```
pairOfLines="cough\tbough"

l = re.findall(r'(?:.*?(\w{3})\b)', pairOfLines)
print(l)
['ugh', 'ugh']
```

- `(?:...)` - non-capturing outer-group
- `(\w{3})\b` - solitary capture group, of which

  - `\w{3}`  - 3 letters
  - `\b` - word boundary

Comment: And how i need to write regexp whith match for "quod erat demonstrandum\
tand that, ladies and gentlemen, is the end of my memorandum". i need to compare last 3 letters of each part

Comment: @AvoAsatryan Honestly speaking, the modification isn't far off, but I would highly recommend trying it first, and opening a new question if it doesn't work out. All the best :)

Answer (score 4):

You can just split:

```
pairOfLines="cough\tbough"
val1, val2 = pairOfLines.split("\t")
if val1[-3:] == val2[-3:]:
   #do something
```

However, if you want to implement regex, you can use `re.split()`:

```
import re

val1, val2 = re.split("\t", pairOfLines)
if val1[-3:] == val2[-3:]:
   #do something
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I need to use match instead of split

Answer (score 1):

you could use regex [backreference](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html) to match the capturing text twice

```
pairOfLines="cough\tbough"
pattern = r'(\w{3})\b.*?\1\b'
match = re.search(pattern, pairOfLines)
# match.group(1) = 'ugh'
```

match will return the match object if it fullfill the regex which match the last 3 char twice, else it will return None

for example, if pairOfLines = "cough\tough**s**", match will return None

- `(\w{3})`  - 1st capturing group of last 3 char
- `\b`       - end of
  word boundary
- `.*?(\1)`  - non greedy match of any char follow by
  matching of 1st capturing group again
- `\b`       - end of word
  boundary